# Use Kurento and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kurento

I am currently trying to use Kurento in a web browser. I have managed to deploy a Kurento Media Server and it's perfectly working in Firefox using the Kurento Utils. I can stream and watch a stream.

The problem is that I can stream in Chrome, but I can't watch a stream. I do not get any IceCandidate from the server and the remote Url is blank...

Is anyone succeeded in watching a stream using Kurento Media Server and Kurento Utils in Google Chrome ?

Regards,

Comment: chrome requires https communication, is your code running on https ??

Comment: Yes I have done it. :), in fact you can do it too, create a media server, download any of the tutorials and then run them, the samples work on both firefox and chrome, you have to use https though